# Drupal - add custom JS and CSS to a panel

Tags: javascript, css, drupal

I am trying to add custom CSS and JS to a page that is using a panel for the content. It's likely that there will be several pages varying in content and structure so I can't really use anything that requires changing the style.css or scripts.js, etc.

I have seen the Panels CSS/JS module, but I was wondering if there is a different way to do it then using that module as the module is only yellow (not recommended) so I'm hesitant to use it.

Answer (score 0):

im only begginer as well but i think a combo of those 2 modules will be the solution

1)https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector

2)https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector

the second one is quite established (26,000 sites use it) the first is less used (6000 sites or so) but both are stable and can be easily learned from youtube guides